# cryptographically good random elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves

After an answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14855/64-bit-elliptic-curve-key/14861#14861), about generate elliptic curves, I've start thinking about the algorithm. The mentioned algorithm will produce curves in the Weierstraß Reduced Form (WRF) over finite fields:

> $y^2 = x^3 + ax +b$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{F}_p$

And this WRF is the representation used in the [NIST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography#NIST-recommended_elliptic_curves) (where $a\equiv-3\pmod p$), [Brainpool](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5639), and probably some others, that can be used in standards like the [extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6637) for [OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) or [TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492).

But this is only one of many ways to describe elliptic curves. In [TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-5.1.1) specification it opens to the possibility to use arbitrary curve definition. Or other alternatives are [Montgomery curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve) like the  [curve25519](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) "recently" proposed for [EdDSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA).

If I like to generate my curve (ignoring the fact that this would affect the maths in the implementations) are there differences between representations? I mean, would be faster to generate random cryptographically good curves depending on the representation? Will curves with different representation and the same bit length, have the same strength?

Comment: Montgomery curves allow a fast constant time ladder calculation of scalar multiplication, Weierstrass curves are quite slow to do this, so usually a non constant time calculation is done, which is bad. For Montgomery curves of a certain construction it can also be proven that the calculation is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not all curves are created equal. For one thing, the number of points on an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbf{F}_p$ varies in the interval $[p+1-2\sqrt{p},p+1+2\sqrt{p}]$ ([Hasse's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves)). There are also [weak instances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography#Domain_parameters) which must be avoided, the most catastrophic being when the number of points on the curve is exactly equal to $p$ (anomalous curves) or to $p+1$ (supersingular curves).

Comment: @figlesquidge Using $\mathbf{F}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a personal choice, please respect that.

Comment: Of course its your answer, feel free to do what you want with it! Just changed that since generally that would be a typo. Hope you didn't mind the link being added :)

Comment: I had hit Enter too soon, sorry. ;)